# Multiple Listeners from one Queue RabbitMQ Spring

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I'am stuyding a sample exemple, have one queue and 2 listeners from this queue, little question and the problem... When have much messages, supose the threads are killing yourself, when have low messages come normals

First Listener

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "FilaSoftware")
    public void receiver(UsuarioModel fileBody) {
        System.out.println("Mensagem Nome - " + fileBody.getNome() + " com a idade " + String.valueOf(fileBody.getIdade()));

    }
```

Second Listener

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "FilaSoftware")
    public void receiver(AlunoModel aluno) {
        System.out.println("Aluno Nome - " + String.valueOf(aluno.getNomeAluno()) + " sala - " + String.valueOf(aluno.getSalaAluno()) + " numero - " + String.valueOf(aluno.getNumeroAluno()));

    }
```

And return this values

```
Mensagem Nome - null com a idade 0
Aluno Nome - Aluno 99 sala - 99 numero - 99
Mensagem Nome - Usuario numero 75 com a idade 75
Aluno Nome - Aluno 39 sala - 39 numero - 39
Mensagem Nome - null com a idade 0
Aluno Nome - Aluno 80 sala - 80 numero - 80
Mensagem Nome - null com a idade 0
Aluno Nome - null sala - 0 numero - 0
Mensagem Nome - null com a idade 0
Aluno Nome - Aluno 40 sala - 40 numero - 40
Mensagem Nome - null com a idade 0
Aluno Nome - Aluno 8 sala - 8 numero - 8
Mensagem Nome - Usuario numero 89 com a idade 89
Aluno Nome - Aluno 67 sala - 67 numero - 67
```

Here my config file

```
 private static final String QUEUE_SOFTWARE = "FilaSoftware";

    @Bean
    Queue queueSoftware() {
        return new Queue(QUEUE_SOFTWARE, false);
    }

    @Bean
    Exchange exchangeDefault() {
        return ExchangeBuilder.topicExchange("ExchangeSoftware")
                .durable(false)
                .autoDelete()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queueSoftware())
                .to(exchangeDefault())
                .with("keyAPI")
                .noargs();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter listnerMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate (final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(listnerMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
```

Here the publishers

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 250L)
    public void runAluno() {
            System.out.println("Publicando mensagem aluno na mensageria");
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNum = random.nextInt(100);
            AlunoModel alunoModel = new AlunoModel();
            alunoModel.setNomeAluno("Aluno " + String.valueOf(randomNum));
            alunoModel.setNumeroAluno(randomNum);
            alunoModel.setSalaAluno(randomNum);
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("ExchangeSoftware", "keyAPI", alunoModel);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L)
    public void runUsuario() {

            System.out.println("Publicando mensagem usuario na mensageria");
            UsuarioModel usuarioModel = new UsuarioModel();
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNum = random.nextInt(100);
            usuarioModel.setNome("Usuario numero " + String.valueOf(randomNum));
            usuarioModel.setIdade(randomNum);
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("ExchangeSoftware", "keyAPI", usuarioModel);
    }
```

Can give a help? :)

Note: I'am using random to generate values like 'idade (number)'

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. You are more than welcome to post an answer of your own (and even accept it, eventually) if you like; but please don't make edits to the question to answer it.

Comment: Right, +1 for moving a solution to the answer. That is really going to be an indicator for us that question has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This was added as an edit to the question by the OP.
>   Because the question should remain a question, this is being moved to an answer.
>   The OP should ideally accept this to mark the question as resolved.

Solved the problem with a classmapper to jackson in my consumer config

```
@Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter listnerMessageConverter(){
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();

        Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
        idClassMapping.put(
                "com.rabbitmq.example.AlunoModel", AlunoModel.class);
        idClassMapping.put(
                "com.rabbitmq.example.UsuarioModel", UsuarioModel.class);
        classMapper.setIdClassMapping(idClassMapping);
        converter.setClassMapper(classMapper);

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate (final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(listnerMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
```

Changed my listeners for this:

```
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues = "FilaSoftware")
public class EventFilter {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventFilter.class);

    @RabbitHandler
    public void receiver(UsuarioModel fileBody) {
        System.out.println("Mensagem Nome - " + fileBody.getNome() + " com a idade " + String.valueOf(fileBody.getIdade()));
    }

    @RabbitHandler
    public void receiver(AlunoModel aluno) {
        System.out.println("Aluno Nome - " + String.valueOf(aluno.getNomeAluno()) + " sala - " + String.valueOf(aluno.getSalaAluno()) + " numero - " + String.valueOf(aluno.getNumeroAluno()));
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
Mensagem Nome - Usuario numero 70 com a idade 70
Aluno Nome - Aluno 83 sala - 83 numero - 83
Aluno Nome - Aluno 56 sala - 56 numero - 56
Aluno Nome - Aluno 48 sala - 48 numero - 48
Aluno Nome - Aluno 24 sala - 24 numero - 24
Mensagem Nome - Usuario numero 7 com a idade 7
Aluno Nome - Aluno 44 sala - 44 numero - 44
Aluno Nome - Aluno 70 sala - 70 numero - 70
Aluno Nome - Aluno 55 sala - 55 numero - 55
Aluno Nome - Aluno 96 sala - 96 numero - 96
```